# How to split a string some number of characters before end of line?

Tags: ruby

I would like to split strings like `"12:30am"` and `"6:55pm"` and separate the `am`/`pm` from the time. Is there a way to use `String#split` to do that?

Alternatively, is there a better way to turn that string in to a `Time` object?

Comment: I see no point of using split here.Rather you can just use `strftime` without `%p` http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special. All you need to do is use the `"time"` library.

```
require "time"
Time.parse "12:30am"
# => 2014-05-04 00:30:00 +0900
Time.parse "6:55pm"
# => 2014-05-04 18:55:00 +0900
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like `Time.parse("12:00am".gsub(/am|pm/i, ""))` to get any of those endings off.  The gsub will remove those characters based on the `/am|pm/i` regex.  The pipe being an or and the i makes it case insensitive.  Check out [rubular](http://rubular.com/) for help using gsub or any regex in ruby.

As for better time methods, I would recommend trying the [gem chronic](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic) for more flexible, expressive time methods.  Here are some examples from its documentation.

```
require 'chronic'

Time.now   #=> Sun Aug 27 23:18:25 PDT 2006

Chronic.parse('tomorrow')
  #=> Mon Aug 28 12:00:00 PDT 2006

Chronic.parse('monday', :context => :past)
  #=> Mon Aug 21 12:00:00 PDT 2006

Chronic.parse('this tuesday 5:00')
  #=> Tue Aug 29 17:00:00 PDT 2006

Chronic.parse('this tuesday 5:00', :ambiguous_time_range => :none)
  #=> Tue Aug 29 05:00:00 PDT 2006

Chronic.parse('may 27th', :now => Time.local(2000, 1, 1))
  #=> Sat May 27 12:00:00 PDT 2000

Chronic.parse('may 27th', :guess => false)
  #=> Sun May 27 00:00:00 PDT 2007..Mon May 28 00:00:00 PDT 2007

Chronic.parse('6/4/2012', :endian_precedence => :little)
  #=> Fri Apr 06 00:00:00 PDT 2012

Chronic.parse('INVALID DATE')
  #=> nil
```

Comment: If you do `gsub(/am|pm/i, "")` and parse that, you will lose the am/pm distinction.